# The page lifecycle for controls(order constructed from a page)

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, containers, page-lifecycle

For example, lets say I have a page and 2 custom controls on that page. During what event on page do these controls get constructed. When does their page_init get called?

Also, for these 2 custom controls, do they both get constructed before either of the page_init events get called?

I've done some testing with a debugger and such, but I'm wanting a definite answer to these questions. I'm not wanting to make code that works only sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official page in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) describes the page lifecycle in details, but a picture is worth a thousand words :

[image: ASP.Net lifecycle]

If I understand correctly, controls are constructed between the `PreInit` and `Init` of the page. Thus, controls' `Init` methods are called before the page's `Init` method.

According to the schema, `Construct` and `FrameworkInitialize` are called on **each** control **before** the `Init` event are fired, which means that all controls should be constructed and available when entering a specific control's `Init` method.

Comment: Ok, but this doesn't answer the more important question. Will all of the controls on a page be constructed before calling any of the controls' `init` methods?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not understand the question like that. I will edit my answer.

Comment: *prints schema and hangs on wall* Wow, that diagram almost gives too much info lol.

Comment: That's exactly what I did ;) ! Make sure to pring it large enough such that you don't have to come too close to read it !